# Define random variable with desired property

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading *Casella's Statistical Inference (2nd ed)*, lemma 11.2.7
In proof, he claims followings:

> If we define random variables $B$ and $V$ by $P(B= \frac{b_i}{c_i}, V=v_i) = \frac{c_i}{C}, i=1,\cdots,k$, where $C=\sum c_i$. Then $EB=\sum \frac{b_i}{c_i} \frac{c_i}{C} = 0$

(last equality comes from $\sum{b_i}=0$, which we assume in proof)
I have two questions:

1. how can we actually define these variables? how can we argue the existence of such random variables?
2. we define probability when both $B$, $V$ are such values. However, how can we claim that $P(B=\frac{b_i}{c_i}) = \frac{c_i}{C}$? I think he use this equation to calculate expectation of$B$. But we define probability only when both variables are simultaneously given. How can I understand this?

In first question, I think we can define variable $B$ so that $P(B=\frac{b_i}{c_i})=\frac{c_i}{C}$, which is obvious. But, as similar reason of second question, we define only probability when both variables are simultaneously given. So I think there is some incompleteness in definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $C=\sum c_i$ implies that $\sum P(B=\frac {b_i} {c_i},V=v_i)=1$. If construct $B$ we can take $V=v_i$ when $B=\frac {b_i} {c_i}$ (or $V=\sum v_i I_{\{B=\frac {b_i} {c_i}\}}$).

It follows now that $(B=\frac {b_i} {c_i},V=v_i)$ is same as the event $B=\frac {b_i} {c_i}$ so $B$ takes the values $\frac {b_i} {c_i}$ with probability $\frac {c_i} {C}$. Hence, $EB =\sum \frac {b_i} {c_i} \frac {c_i} {C}$.

Comment: That's very clear. Thanks!